# Efficient algorithms for checking non-emptiness of the language of a Turing machine

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, formal-methods

I know that language non-emptiness is TM recognizable, and one can perform a BFS to find an input string that TM accepts, if there is any. But, what is the most efficient algorithm for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "algorithm" and "efficient" here?

Comment: Breadth-first search of what?

Comment: The memory complexity of BFS is not good. I wonder if you guys any better algorithm and point out me some references.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is undecidable. There are no algorithms for it, so there are no efficient algorithms.

Comment: I *think* he may want an algorithm that finds a witness quickly *if there is one*. That's probably intractable in general, but heuristics may apply.

Comment: Raphael is right. Given a TM, it is not possible to show if its language is empty. However, if the language of the TM is nonempty, I'd like to find an input stream that the TM accepts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the very same scheme that is used to simulate Nondeterministic Turing Machine on Deterministic one [like here](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ko/pdfs/lecture-14.pdf), which uses BFS.
In your case accepted string is found in the same manner, otherwise (like DFS) it would not halt. So essentialy the efficiency of time is bounded by such conversion and you cannot do better, because:

- the existence of polynomial time solution would be equivalent to $NTM$ -> $DTM$ simulation which is the same as solving $P$ vs $NP$
- any heuristic is in the mean sense worse than BFS

The efficiency of memory might be decreased if you encode your TM (like UTM does) and in the every step use only one at the time (memory efficient, time inefficient). Algorithms like Branch and Bound (with indication that when no heuristic is available use DFS) cannot be used.